# How to create a time penalty with coroutine in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a 2D game in Unity. The game is limited to 60 seconds. I would like to have a time bomb which causes time reduction when the player hit the bomb.

In my script, I have a boolean which is named as `"hitDetect"` and I use a `Coroutine()` for the countdown.

I tried to push the bomb to the right side when the player hit the bomb and then check whether the collision takes place with these codes:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D bombcol)
{
    if(bombcol.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        bombcol.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.right * hitForce);
    }
    hitDetect = true;
}
```

This is my `Coroutine()` function which provides me to have a game which is successfully limited to 60 seconds except for the time penalty:

```
IEnumerator LoseTime()
{
    while (true) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
        timeLeft--; 
        if (hitDetect == true)
        {
            timeLeft= timeLeft - 5;
        }
    }
}
```

I also set the `"hitDetect"` as false in the start body.

```
void Start () 
    {
        StartCoroutine("LoseTime");
        hitDetect = false;
    }
```

However, these methods don't lead me to success. When the player hit the bomb, time penalty doesn't work. Where is my mistake? What would you recommend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend to calculate the time in the `Update()` function. So you can be sure the hitDetect is observed every frame and the penalty is set only once if you reset `hitDetect` after subtracting the penalty.

```
public bool hitDetect = false;
public float timeLeft = 60.0f;
public float penaltyTime = 5.0f;

void Start(){
    timeLeft = 60.0f;
    hitDetect = false;
}

void Update(){
    timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
    if(hitDetect){
        timeLeft -= penaltyTime;

        // reset the hit!
        hitDetect = false;
    }

    if(timeLeft < 0.0f){
        // end game?
    }
}
```

With this code your time is subtracted once by the penalty value if `hitDetect` is set `true` by your collision.

Hope this helps!